# Permission denied as a command but not from SSH in Terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

I have a script that calls an API and, grabs photos and saves them to the server. It works wonderfully if I execute it from SSH. But when it's running as a Scheduled Task, I receive a `failed to open stream: Permission denied`

This is what I'm running as my scheduled task:

`/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/laravel/artisan get_photo`

Again, running this script as `php artisan get_photo` from Terminal through SSH works wonders. I can't figure out why I would be getting `Permission denied` when it's being run as a Scheduled Task.

Comment: And the permissions are..?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening was because when I ran the script through SSH, the user was "root" ... which of course is not the same user that the Please Scheduled Tasks uses to run the command.

DUH!